# Content Security Policy in IE support

Tags: internet-explorer-9, bho, content-security-policy

I am aware of Content Security Policy as a new feature build into IE10.

Wondering if there is any 3rd party vendors providing implementation thru add-on(BHO) for IE9 and older version?

Thanks,

Comment: I couldn't tell you, but why not just upgrade from IE9 to IE10?

Answer (score 0):

IE 10 only runs on windows 8 and there is only a preview version available for windows 7. IE 9 on the other hand is the browser already used by the majority of IE users so having a solution that works on IE 9 allows the deployment of content security policy from a website without requiring their clients to upgrade to IE 10. Having a BHO would be very helpful in ie 9 for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Older than IE 10, use  [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

IE 10 and newer, use [X-Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

For me X-Content-Security-Policy worked in IE 9 as well.